# Installing Software in a batch file based on the prescence of a Registry Key

Tags: batch-file, scripting, registry

I am trying to install the latest version of some software via a batch file.
Each version has a unique string value so I would like to install the latest version only if the value in the registry is not of the latest version.

The following is part of my batch file:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B} /f 1.3.0.13565 if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 goto INSTALL if %ErrorLevel% EQU 1 goto END
```

The issue is that this does not work. The string name is `DisplayVersion` but if I type in `if %DisplayVersion% EQU 1.3.0.13565` this doesn't work either. Perhaps I shouldn't be using `ErrorLevel`? Is it possible to say `if DisplayVersion equals to 1.3.0.13565 then GOTO INSTALL else END`?

EDIT:

My batch file now looks like this:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B}" /F "1.3.0.13565" /Reg:32 1> NUL 2>&1 || Exit /B

:INSTALL
msiexec /x {731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B} /q
msiexec /i "\\appserve01\share$\Teams\Teams_x64_13028779.msi" ALLUSER=1

:END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line should be sufficient to perform everything your question requested.

```batch-file
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B}" /F "1.3.0.13565" /Reg:32 1> NUL 2>&1 && (GoTo INSTALL) || GoTo END
```

*I don't think it is necessary to make it any more robust, unless you really think that it is possible that the string `1.3.0.13565` could exist elsewhere in the values or data under that key.*

Comment: Hi,  Apologies for the delay in responding, I just noticed your reply.  Thank you so much for coming back to me and for the code.  Unfortunately, when I run the above line of code in my batch file, nothing happens.  Also I am not entirely sure what the following is meant to do: /Reg:32 1> NUL 2>&1 &&. I ultimately need the batch file to GoTo Install if that key exists or to END if it doesn't.  Thank you again.

Comment: The command I posted works exactly as I posted it, without any additions, removals, or modifications in any way. If you have not run it without modification, I need to see exactly what you modified to assist you further.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  The following is in the batch file:

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B}" /F "1.3.0.13565" /Reg:32 1> NUL 2>&1 && (GoTo INSTALL) || GoTo END

:INSTALL
rem Step 1: Uninstall Microsoft Teams 1.3.0.13565
msiexec /x {731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B} /q

rem Step 2: Install Microsoft Teams 1.3.0.28779
msiexec /i "\\appserver01\applications$\Teams\Teams_x64_13028779.msi" ALLUSER=1

:END

Comment: My command line above is part of your batch file, but I have never seen it, so can only base my response on what I know. Currently the only thing I do know, is that the command I've provided above, in isolation, will do what you wanted. Whether the rest of your batch file is correctly written and saved to incorporate it, is however, another thing. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65357787/edit) button, to update your question, to include that information, and some debugging information. BTW, do not post formatted code in the comment area, it will be, and is unreadable!

Comment: If you make the very first line of your batch file this: `@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B}" /F "1.3.0.13565" /Reg:32 1> NUL 2>&1 || Exit /B`, then all you need to do is to put your uninstall and install code underneath that line. It will only run if the string, `1.3.0.13565`, is found in the 32-bit registry on a 64-bit Windows machine, or in the normal registry location on a 32-bit only Windows version. All of that of course may depend upon what versions of Windows you're aiming this script at.

Comment: Hi,  I have edited the main question and have added the latest lines from the batch file.  It still doesn't run so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am running this on 64 bit Windows machines.  On my current test machine, that value exists but the script still does not run.  Where does it say to go to Install if the key exists?  Thanks so much for your help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: I manually ran the find query and it failed because I didn't included WOW6432Node in the path.  Now when I run the query, it successfully finds the value that I am looking for but the script still does not proceed to the uninstall / install command.  Thanks again

Comment: No, it didn't the `/Reg:32` option deals with the WOW6432Node part of the path, as needed, I included it for a reason. The only reason I can see for it failing is that you're using a very old operating system created before there was such a thing as a 64-bit version.

Comment: Start by replacing everything in your batch file except for the first line I've already provided, with `@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T -1`. Then double-click on the batch file to run it, and report back exactly what happens.

Comment: I have done that and receive the following:

'\\appserve01\share$\Teams'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

Comment: Get rid of that line, my comments were 100% clear. You should have only two lines in your batch file, **1.** `@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B}" /F "1.3.0.13565" /Reg:32 1> NUL 2>&1 || Exit /B`, and **2.** `@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T -1`. Now doubleclick on it, and report back the results.

Comment: Hi, My batch file does only include those above 2 lines.  I believe it referenced the UNC path as I was running the batch from from that UNC path.  I have moved the 2 line batch file to the local PC and now it simply says press any key to continue when I run it.

Comment: As you're reporting the "Press any key…" message it shows that my command is working 100% correctly. If the registry key did not exist the `timeout.exe` utility would not have run, and that message would not have appeared. The issue now with your script, is your other commands, but as those are out of the scope of your asked question, they are irrelevant.

Comment: Fantastic. The script works when I run it locally but doesn't work when I run it from a UNC path.  Do you know why this might be?

Comment: You have not provided sufficient information for me to answer you, but, as I stated, those things are outside of the scope of the question you had asked, and I had answered. What you should do, is mark my answer as accepted, and ask a new question, if you have further issues outside of what was asked and answered here, linking to it if necessary. you could even potentially edit your duplicate, which you've since deleted, and undelete it, if you find that easier. What happens when you use `@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "\\MACHINE\HKLM…`, where `MACHINE` is the name of the appropriate PC?

Comment: When I run the query with the machine name it works and I get the result that I am querying.  I will mark this as answered and will post another question if I cannot get to the bottom of this.  Thank you so much for your assistance with this, you have been a great help.